# What is "To litter the foul center-table" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Although i know meaning of each word one by one in this sentence in Mark Twain's short story "About Barbers" I cannot understand what is "to litter" and "foul center-table" in the context.

Thanks for your help!

> Finally, I searched out the least dilapidated of last year's illustrated papers that littered the foul center-table, and conned their unjustifiable misrepresentations of old forgotten events.

Comment: Did you look up [*litter* as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litter), and do you still have confusion?

Answer (score 3):

Lexico [defines](https://www.lexico.com/definition/litter) "litter" (vb.) as "Make (a place or area) untidy with rubbish or a large number of objects left lying about", e.g. ‘clothes and newspapers littered the floor’.

In this case, illustrated newspapers litter the centre-table ("any table placed in the centre of a room").

Presumably, the centre-table is described as foul because it is dirty or messy.

Answer (score 1):

These are straight from the dictionary:

> *litter* make (a place or area) untidy with rubbish or a large number of objects left lying about.
>
> > "clothes and newspapers littered the floor"

So there are a large number of "illustrated papers" (Cheap newspapers with pictures, in contrast to the more serious newspapers that were all text) scattered at random on the table.

> *foul* repulsive or disgusting.

The table in the centre of the room was disgusting in some way, probably it hasn't been cleaned, and as this a barbershop there might be shaving cream, hair, perhaps blood on the table.